# Pointer-to-Pointer and linked list, passing parameters per value

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Background is that I am experimenting with pointer-to-pointer in C by implementing a linked list. My question is regarding the difference in the two pieces of code and why the first one is giving expected output, but not the other one. Why does the first piece of code not advance head "outsite" the function which code 2 seems to do?

```
void add_node(int x, Node **head){
if(*head == NULL){
    Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(new_node));
    new_node->x = x;
    *head = new_node;
} else {
    Node *n = *head;

    while(n->next != NULL){
        n = n->next;
    }

    Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(new_node));
    new_node->x = x;
    n->next = new_node;
}
}
```

Output is as expected if I add 4 elements and after each addition print the list: 
1 | 12 | 123 | 1234

```
void add_node(int x, Node **head){
if(*head == NULL){
    Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(new_node));
    new_node->x = x;
    *head = new_node;
} else {
    while((*head)->next != NULL){
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }

    Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(new_node));
    new_node->x = x;
    (*head)->next = new_node;
}
}
```

Output is following: 1 | 12 | 23 | 34

Comment: `Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->x = x;new_node->next=NULL;`

Comment: `*head = (*head)->next;` this update `*head`, It is no longer at the top of the list.

Comment: Allocation size is incorrect, should be `malloc(sizeof(Node))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are using the pointer n to travel the linked list, you're assigning it to n->next, which is exactly what you want to do to travel a linked list.
In the second example, you are changing what the head pointer is pointing to:

```
*head = (*head)->next;
```

You're essentially moving the beginning of the linked list to another node, that's why you're having such behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. What confused my in the beginning was why they were different but I see it now. Is it a good way to do it or are there any obvious better ways?

Comment: If you believe this is correct, Mark it as accepted please :)

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate input 1,2,3 and focus on the head.

```
while((*head)->next != NULL){
    *head = (*head)->next;
}
Node *new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(new_node));
        new_node->x = x;
        (*head)->next = new_node;
```

leaves the head pointing somewhere, which your output is depicting ;)

For input 1 and 1,2 the conditions are not met and you escape.

Comment: Allocation size is incorrect, should be `malloc(sizeof(Node))`